# How Can I Transpose 1 Row Into Columns and Have Another Column Autofill?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet with data like so:

```
Timestamp1 Value1 Value2 Value3

Timestamp2 Value1
```

How can I set up an array formula/query/etc? in Google Sheets to have the data formatted like so:

```
Timestamp1 Value1

Timestamp1 Value2

Timestamp1 Value3

Timestamp2 Value1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B1:D<>"", "♠"&A1:A&"♦"&B1:D, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]